# How to create signed Google Cloud Storage URLs in Cloud Function using Cloud Function service account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, service-accounts, google-identity

I am aware that we can create signed GCS URLs using a service account file. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-manually

In my case, what I want is to create signed URLs using the service account of the cloud function, how can I do that?

Comment: Can you share your piece of code? I know it's possible in Python (I submitted the pull request to make it possible), but I have to inspect in other languages if yours is different.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I am also trying this on Python

Answer (score 4):

You can perform that by providing the access token and the email of the service account.

The library will, instead of using the private key locally to sign the url, perform a call to the [Service Account Credentials REST API](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest), and use the method [signBlob](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/signBlob) to sign your URL.

For that, the library need to know the token to use to be authenticated against the API, and the service account to use for performing the signature

```
    credentials, project_id = auth.default()
    if credentials.token is None:
        # Perform a refresh request to populate the access token of the
        # current credentials.
        credentials.refresh(requests.Request())
    client = Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket)
    blob = bucket.blob(blob)
    return blob.generate_signed_url(
        version="v4",
        service_account_email=credentials.service_account_email,
        access_token=credentials.token
    )
```

Comment: This answer is correct. The only gotcha is that Google rotates the key used for signing approximately every 12 hours. Do not create Signed URLs using this method for longer than 12 hours. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#signing-iam

Comment: Wow, really!!! That's a awesome addition and a stunning information! Thank @JohnHanley